# When over 20000 schedules, registering schedule is getting slow

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I built a dynamic web interfaced scheduler with the rufus scheduler. There are about 38000 jobs running. No problem with running jobs. However registering jobs to rufus is too slow. It takes about 6 minutes(355seconds) to register 38000 jobs.

Is there any way to accelerate this? My environments are as below..

```
OS: RHEL 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
Machine: 16 core, 16G
Rufus scheduler: v3.1.0, max thread 100, as singleton
jruby: v1.7.19 (1.9.3p551)
sinatra: v1.4.6 with puma -t 8:8
jruby option: -J-Xmx10240m -J-Xms2048m -J-server
```

I tried several modifications. But there's no big effect on total time.

1. register a job and pause it immediately and resume when registering is finished. (373secs)
2. instanciate new rufus scheduler every 10000 jobs ( 341sec ) - disable singleton
3. instanciate 4 rufus schedulers and distribute jobs to them.. ( 311 sec) - disable singleton

Comment: Could you please indicate in your question what kind of job you schedule: "cron" or "at"? Or what percentage of each in your 10k jobs?

Comment: Could you also please indicate in your answer why you need to schedule 20k jobs in one Ruby process in one go? What's the context?

Comment: @jmettraux A use case  of the application is a substitution of crontab schedule. kind of centralized dynamic batch controller. Somehow this application manages about 10k server's crontab batch jobs now. Most of jobs are recurring jobs like "every" and "cron". 95% every, 5% cron, about 85% 1 minute interval.

Comment: It's ironic to use rufus-scheduler to manage server "real" crontabs.

Comment: I mean move "real" crontab to rufus scheduler. not controlling it.

Comment: Why do you need to schedule 38k jobs in a single batch?

Comment: potential fix https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/commit/ef8047bc95e854f12924774576790b7c6c1accc1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rufus-scheduler is meant to run in environments where threads are used. In order to prevent conflicts when two threads are scheduling simultaneously, there is a mutex "covering" the scheduling.

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/f859e31339bd78330d88f7cee7854d896ada381e/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb#L205
https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/f859e31339bd78330d88f7cee7854d896ada381e/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb#L637
https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/f859e31339bd78330d88f7cee7854d896ada381e/lib/rufus/scheduler/job_array.rb#L44

As you can see, there is also a check to see whether the job already got scheduled somehow.

> Is there any way to accelerate this?

Submit an issue at https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues with a link back to this StackOverflow question and you'll get help. Don't forget to include the information I requested in the comments above.

Best regards.

**UPDATE**

I tested on my MacBook and the results are here: https://gist.github.com/jmettraux/b3f2bacb2a59627aea00

I get between 13s (Ruby 2.1) and 37s (Ruby 1.9). JRuby clocks at 16s.

Rufus-scheduler 3.2.0 pre.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Actually I used 1 thread to register schedules, not multi.. So I guess the mutex isn't the bottleneck? try some more test and then I'll submit the issue at github.

Comment: I guess you're right the mutex although it has a cost, is cheaper than the "already scheduled check" included. I don't think it needs more testing, just fill the issue as a "feature request".

Comment: I found it. It was cron type job. Scheduling in various cron schedule is slow..

[https://gist.github.com/kssminus/8e26f1950056011a3499](https://gist.github.com/kssminus/8e26f1950056011a3499)

I scheduled in only 1000 jobs and it took 83 seconds. Maybe do I need to submit the issue on github?